# Confusion about definition of an almost everywhere continuous function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $1_\mathbb{Q}$ be the indicator of the rational numbers. Is $1_\mathbb{Q}$ continuous almost everywhere?

From what I understand, this is not true. I would say that $1_\mathbb{Q}$ is continuous nowhere. But if I restrict the domain to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. I remove a set of measure zero), then $1_\mathbb{Q} \equiv 0$ and is continuous. Some of the responses I've seen seem to consider this as being "continuous almost everywhere". For example: [Measurability of almost everywhere continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580305/measurability-of-almost-everywhere-continuous-functions)

Which definition is correct/standard?

Comment: A function is continuous almost everywhere if the set of discontinuity is a null set. Obviously, $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}$ is not, because as you remarked, it's continuous nowhere, and thus the set of discontinuity has infinite measure. Nevertheless, it's has a continuous represent, i.e. there is a continuous function $f$ s.t. $f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}$ almost everywhere. Namely, if $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, then $f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: A continuous a-e function is not the same as a function that is eual a.e. to a continuous function.

Comment: In the post that I linked to, the proof seems to imply a weaker statement, i.e. a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable if $f|_E$ is continuous where $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is a set of measure zero. Is that correct?

Comment: @klein4 Yes. More generally for a complete measure space - i.e. a measure space $(X,\mathcal E,\mu)$ such that $A\in\mathcal E$ for all $A\subseteq X$ such that there is some $B\in\mathcal E$ such that $\mu(B)=0$ and $B\supseteq A$ - a function which is equal almost-everywhere to a measurable function is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

When you restrict to $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q},$ you're changing the topology. This is a subtle but important point.

The criterion you describe says that in the original topology, the function is continuous at almost every point. This is **not** the same as "when you remove a null set, the restricted function is continuous on that subspace topology."

A similar confusion arises in Lusin's theorem, which says that if $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there's $F$ so that $f$ **restricted to** $F$ is continuous and $m(F) > 1-\epsilon.$

Just because $f$ restricted to $F$ is continuous at a point $p \in F,$ doesn't mean that $f$ is continuous at $p$. $f$ and the restriction of $f$ onto $F$ are two different functions on two different topological spaces.